# How much faster is SLIM compared to HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, haml, benchmarking, slim-lang

I'm trying to convince my team members to use SLIM instead of HAML because I like SLIM's syntax a lot more. I was promised that we would change to SLIM if it was really a lot faster than HAML as I read [here](https://github.com/stonean/slim#benchmarks) and [here](https://gist.github.com/626215), but I don't know how recent these benchmarks are, so I wanted to know whether anybody has some real life experience with this topic?

I am also not really sure which of the benchmarks (compiled, tilt compiled, cached, uncached) does mean the most, as I don't know what exactly will be used when a Rails application is in production mode (where the speed is the most needed).

Thanks a lot for more information about this topic!

Comment: I suspect that to convince your sceptical colleagues you're going to have to present convincing evidence which is very specific to your circumstances.  Appealing to an oracle, even one as august as Stack Overflow, is, I propose, a waste of your time, which would be better spent deriving and executing your own benchmarks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slim is about 5 to 10 times faster in production mode. The releavant benchmark is the compiled and tilt compiled mode. Uncached is not relevant in production because it benchmarks the parser performance.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Did you close the topic? Or how did it happen that it's closed now?